# React Array.map does not recognise JSON data as array

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, react-redux

It is probably a very simple fix, but I haven't been able to figure out why the map function doesn't recognise the input as an array.

I have a Dilemma model which contains an array of user comments. I fetch the data and map it to the state of my react component. Then i try to parse the data as props to a subcomponent where i attempt to map the data.

**Dilemma reducer**

```
const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  dilemma: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_DILEMMA:
      return {
        ...state,
        dilemma: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case GET_DILEMMAS:
      return {
        ...state,
        dilemmas: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case CREATE_DILEMMA:
      return {
        ...state,
        dilemmas: [action.payload, ...state.dilemmas]
      };
    case DELETE_DILEMMA:
      return {
        ...state,
        dilemmas: state.dilemmas.filter(
          dilemma => dilemma._id !== action.payload
        )
      };
    case DILEMMAS_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**this.props in the stateful component**

```
{
  "match": { "path": "/", "url": "/", "isExact": true, "params": {} },
  "location": { "pathname": "/", "search": "", "hash": "", "key": "crpcmj" },
  "history": {
    "length": 50,
    "action": "POP",
    "location": { "pathname": "/", "search": "", "hash": "", "key": "crpcmj" }
  },
  "dilemmas": {
    "loading": false,
    "dilemma": {
      "red_votes": 0,
      "blue_votes": 0,
      "_id": "5b855fcbdfa436e0d25765fa",
      "user": "5b855f9fdfa436e0d25765f9",
      "prefix": "Hvis du skulle vælge",
      "title": "Svede remoulade",
      "red": "Gå med rustning resten af dit liv",
      "blue": "Svede remoulade resten af dit liv",
      "likes": [],
      "comments": [
        {
          "date": "2018-08-28T17:28:23.340Z",
          "_id": "5b858637b6f6a6e6218eeaba",
          "user": "5b855f9fdfa436e0d25765f9",
          "text": "This is a test3 comment",
          "author": "Albyzai"
        },
        {
          "date": "2018-08-28T17:28:19.915Z",
          "_id": "5b858633b6f6a6e6218eeab9",
          "user": "5b855f9fdfa436e0d25765f9",
          "text": "This is a test2 comment",
          "author": "Albyzai"
        },
        {
          "date": "2018-08-28T15:50:18.792Z",
          "_id": "5b856f3aed156de48a270766",
          "user": "5b855f9fdfa436e0d25765f9",
          "text": "This is a test comment",
          "author": "Albyzai"
        }
      ],
      "date": "2018-08-28T14:44:27.413Z",
      "slug": "svede-remoulade",
      "__v": 3
    }
  },
  "errors": {}
}
```

**Stateful component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import propTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getDilemma, addLike, removeLike } from "../../actions/dilemmaActions";

import Dilemma from "./../dilemma/Dilemma";
import Divider from "./../dilemma/Divider";
import CommentFeed from "../dilemma/CommentFeed";

class DilemmaLayout extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      title: "",
      prefix: "",
      red: "",
      blue: "",
      red_votes: 0,
      blue_votes: 0,
      likes: [],
      comments: [],
      errors: {}
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
    }

    if (nextProps.dilemmas.dilemma) {
      const dilemma = nextProps.dilemmas.dilemma;

      this.setState({
        id: dilemma._id,
        user: dilemma.user,
        title: dilemma.title,
        prefix: dilemma.prefix,
        red: dilemma.red,
        blue: dilemma.blue,
        red_votes: dilemma.red_votes,
        blue_votes: dilemma.blue_votes,
        likes: [dilemma.likes],
        comments: [dilemma.comments]
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>        
        <CommentFeed comments={this.state.comments} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

DilemmaLayout.propTypes = {
  getDilemma: propTypes.func.isRequired,
  addLike: propTypes.func.isRequired,
  removeLike: propTypes.func.isRequired,
  dilemmas: propTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  dilemmas: state.dilemmas,
  errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getDilemma, addLike, removeLike }
)(DilemmaLayout);
```

**Functional component receiving props**

```
import React from "react";
import Comment from "./Comment";
import { Container } from "reactstrap";

const CommentFeed = comments => {
  const commentArray = comments.map(comment => {
    <Comment author={comment.author} text={comment.text} />;
  });

  return <Container>{commentArray}</Container>;
};

export default CommentFeed;
```

Comment: in your CommentFeed function, console.log the comments to see what it is...

Comment: it returns `{"comments":[]}`, so it must be the way that i parse it to the sub component which causes the problem.

Comment: Yeah (from answer comments below) please post your reducer and so on - something is wrong with the comments/dilemmas...

Comment: I have updated the post with JSON data from the this.props in the stateful component, as well as the reducer.

Comment: Did the StackBlitz example help? I think this really comes down to some basic conditional rendering.

Comment: To be fair, I am not entirely sure what helped, all of a sudden it just magically worked. I am however quite sure that it was unrelated to conditional rendering. I think the most reasonable guess is that I had an unsaved file somewhere. Actually i didn't notice the StackBlitz example until now.

Comment: You may want to create an answer and mark it solved with whatever steps you took for closure, if different than what was suggested in the existing answers. Glad to hear it's working, happy coding!

Comment: I would have, if I knew what actually fixed the problem. And i really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try using something like ES6 [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) to extract/unpack prop `comments` from `props` on the `CommentFeed` component. This needs to be done because the `comments` array is **not** directly passed to the component, instead an `props` object is passed to the component that contains a `comments` property.

```
const CommentFeed = ({ comments }) => {
  const commentArray = comments.map(comment =>
    <Comment author={comment.author} text={comment.text} />;
  );

  return <Container>{commentArray}</Container>;
};
```

Or access `comments` such as `props.comments`:

```
const CommentFeed = props => {
  const commentArray = props.comments.map(comment =>
    <Comment author={comment.author} text={comment.text} />;
  );

  /* also an option
    const { comments } = props;
    const commentArray = comments.map(comment => {
      <Comment author={comment.author} text={comment.text} />;
    });
  */

  return <Container>{commentArray}</Container>;
};
```

Additionally, it's not possible to tell from what's provided, but the following setting of state could be causing issues for a couple of reasons:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.errors) {
    this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
  }

  if (nextProps.dilemmas.dilemma) {
    const dilemma = nextProps.dilemmas.dilemma;

    this.setState({
      // ...
      likes: [dilemma.likes],
      comments: [dilemma.comments]
    });
  }
}
```

1. If `dilemma.likes` is meant to be an array. You either just need to `likes: dilemma.likes` or `likes: [...dilemma.likes]`.
2. If `dilemma.comments` is meant to be an array. You either just need to `comments: dilemma.comments` or `comments: [...dilemma.comments]`.

There could be an issue where a nested array is being created such as `[[]]` which cause the error you described in the `comments.map()` in the `CommentFeed` component as `map()` would be trying to access property `author` of a nested array item like `[{ "author":"Albyzai" }].author`.

Given that [componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) will be deprecated in the future, why not just use `comments` and other properties coming from the store to pass to child components or render? You mentioned in comments that various props are undefined/null at the time of initial render. You will probably need to use the `loading` property in your store's state in combination with some sort of conditional rendering.

```
render() {
  const { dilemmas, errors } = this.props;

  if (errors) {
    return <div>{errors}</div>;
  } else if (!dilemmas.dilemma || dilemmas.loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return <CommentFeed comments={dilemmas.dilemma.comments} />;
  }
}
```

I've created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jzzrhp) showing this functionality in action at a basic level.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Both solutions return 'cannot read property author of undefined' unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure either `comments` from first example or `props.comments` has a value when `CommentsFeed` is rendered? If it does, is an array? Also `const dilemma = nextProps.dilemmas.dilemma;` seems problematic potentially, is `nextProps.dilemmas` an array? If so, you wouldn't be able to access an entry in array using `.` notation.

Comment: This answer solves the issue of accessing `comments` from `props` passed to the functional component. You may need to create a separate question to tackle how the `comments` array is processed by component `Comment`.

Comment: You may need to share your `dilemmas` prop structure in your question. It's not clear how that is structured and what is actually being set with `setState()` including what `nextProps.dilemmas.dilemma` is actually returning.

Comment: I managed to snap a screenshot of the state in the parent component: https://imgur.com/a/DBHg6Ft

Comment: I've updated the answer. I'd recommend avoid [copying props to state](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) and just use the values from the store. Your data structure seems fine, you may just need to carefully ensure you have default values for the arrays and similar utilizing conditional rendering or equivalent. Some errors may be happening if something like `comments` isn't an flat array of objects at some moment. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: The problem seems to be that the props aren't filled before react renders the DOM. So it is trying to render an undefined object. I tried `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props))` which returned undefined twice before it returned the real props. Like this: https://puu.sh/Bmdb5/afa91ea8d4.png

Comment: You should be able to handle this with some conditional rendering, checking that values exist prior to rendering the various components. I've updated the `render()` to demonstrate this at a basic level. You may even consider making `dilemma` equal to undefined/null until it has loading to make it easier.